# How to add padding for multiple fields in a custom scapy packet?

Tags: python, networking, scapy, packet

I am creating a custom packet format for scapy, with this simplified requirement:
add two string fields and padding to have a fixed size layer of X, where X is a hardcoded constant.

I have the following code:

```
class Custom(Packet):
    fields_desc = [        
        FieldLenField("field1_len", None, fmt="B", length_of="field1"),
        StrLenField("field1", None, length_from=lambda pkt: pkt.field1_len),
        FieldLenField("field2_len", None, fmt="B", length_of="field2"),
        StrLenField("field2", None, length_from=lambda pkt: pkt.field2_len
    ]

packet = Ether() / Custom(field1="abcd", field2="efg")
```

In this case, with X=10, I would like to have the bytes "abcdefg000" added to the packet, where the 3 bytes of padding were appended to reach the 10 byte length. In my case other fields will be added after the padding, so it's not the end of the packet padding.

I am aware of the `PadField` object, but that only works with one field. I tried modifying it to accept a list of fields, tried many other possible approaches, but nothing worked well. Seems like something so easy to do, yet I can't find a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `post_build` hook:

```
class Custom(Packet):
    fields_desc = [        
        FieldLenField("field1_len", None, fmt="B", length_of="field1"),
        StrLenField("field1", None, length_from=lambda pkt: pkt.field1_len),
        FieldLenField("field2_len", None, fmt="B", length_of="field2"),
        StrLenField("field2", None, length_from=lambda pkt: pkt.field2_len
    ]

    def post_build(self, pkt, pay):
        pkt += b"\x00" * ((-len(pkt)) % 10)
        return pkt + pay
```

Comment: Would this work if I have other fields besides these 4? I can't add the padding bytes at the end of the packet, I would need to insert them in the middle.

Comment: Then use a `PadField` in the middle (?)

Comment: The `PadField`, as far as I know, only pads one field. That field alone is not enough to give the information to the PadField on how many bytes to pad.